# How to connect Vue 3 with Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I initialized a new, empty Vue application using Vue version 3. I then tried to add the plugin `Vuetify` with the command `vue add vuetify`, but received the following error. Any ideas on how to solve it?

[image: Error: You cannot call "get" on a collection with no paths.]

Answer (score 21):

Currently possible with Vuetify 3:

**Installation**

In order for the installation to proceed correctly, vue-cli 4.0 is required. Further instructions are available at [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). (check with `vue -V`)

Once installed, generate a project with the following command using the vue-cli 4.0:

```bash
vue create my-app
```

When prompted, choose `Vue 3 Preview`:

```bash
? Please pick a preset:
    Default ([Vue 2] babel, eslint)
  > Default (Vue 3 Preview) ([Vue 3] babel, eslint)
    Manually select features
```

It is recommended to commit or stash your changes at this point, in case you need to rollback the changes.

```bash
cd my-app
vue add vuetify
```

Once prompted, choose v3:

```bash
? Choose a preset: (Use arrow keys)
  Default (recommended)
  Prototype (rapid development)
  Configure (advanced)
> v3
```

**Usage**

With Vue 3.0, the initialization process for Vue apps (and by extension Vuetify) has changed. With the new  `createVuetify` method, the options passed to it have also changed. Please see the pages in the Features section of the documentation for further details.

Next, navigate to your project directory and add Vuetify to your project:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import App from "./App";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(vuetify);

app.mount("#app");
```

Source:

- https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#installation
- https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap

Answer (score 12):

As of July 2020 Vue 3 is unsupported by Vuetify 2.x. All components are being refactored for Vue 3 per Vuetify's task task list: https://www.notion.so/d107077314ca4d2896f0eeba49fe8a14?v=5cc7c08e9cc44021a7c86a20f189b0ba

Comment: At this point in time, don't hold your breath - the above board shows 6/124 tasks completed.

Comment: Vuetify 3 is now in Alfa https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/. Beta coming this month (February 2022). So I guess we could start holding the breath :) Anyway, I will start switching to it and Vue 3

Answer (score 10):

While there is no Vuetify 3, I'd use `Vue 2.x` with `Vuetify 2.x` and [install the Composition API as a package/plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api):

```
npm install @vue/composition-api
```

Then importing to your project (in `main.js`):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)
```

And finally using it in your component:

```
// use the APIs
import { ref, reactive } from '@vue/composition-api'
```

Just be aware of the [limitations](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api#limitations) of this method.

Comment: agree with you, this is the best solution for current status.

Answer (score 5):

Vuetify is not currently compatible with Vue 3.

Given the number of breaking changes and implementation differences in Vue 3, the entire library needs to be rewritten.

As of Jan 2021, they are targetting a Quarter 1, 2021 release for an alpha version, but the average user shouldn't expect to see a release version until late in the year, possibly even early 2022.

Until then, there are other alternatives that are Vue 3 compatible, such as [Prime Vue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/). I believe they have Material Design themes that can be connected and a decent number of components (albeit slightly lacking in the v-app style feature coordination).

EDIT: The Vuetify v3 BETA is now available with a full release likely in Summer/Autumn of '22.

Answer (score 1):

You can try vue 3 with the alpha of vuetify https://next.vuetifyjs.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You Must Install Vuetify 3 using the command

```
npm i vuetify@3.0.0-beta.11
```

and add it using the instruction from https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

As of today **Dec-4-2022** Vue 3 is released for Months,
even vuetify@3.0.3 is released but the [latest npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify/v/3.0.0-beta.0?activeTab=versions) is'nt updated it is still in next even its not in beta anymore,
also the [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) is in Maintenance mode [and for a new Vue project they recommend using the Vite base install](https://cli.vuejs.org/#getting-started:%7E:text=For%20new%20projects%2C%20please%20use%20create%2Dvue%20to%20scaffold%20Vite%2Dbased%20projects.%20Also%20refer%20to%20the%20Vue%203%20Tooling%20Guide%20for%20the%20latest%20recommendations.)

so the best solution is to install it from npm with the latest release from GitHub like

```
npm i vuetify@^3.0.0
```

I hope they update it soon so you can install it without the version number