# Why is password validation not working in setup in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am a newbie to vuetify.

To apply password validation, we defined as follows.

```
<v-text-field
                  class="text-body-2"
                  value="test"
                  v-model="password"
                  :append-icon="password_show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                  :rules="[password_rules.required, password_rules.min]"
                  :type="password_show ? 'text' : 'password'"
                  @click:append="password_show = !password_show"
                  outlined
                  clearable
                  background-color="#f7f7f7"
                  :label="$t('word.password')"
                ></v-text-field>
```

```
<script>
import { reactive, toRefs } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { getLoginToken } from '@/api/login';

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      username: '',
      password: '',
      loginForm: null,
      password_show: false,
      username_rules: {
        required: (value) => !!value || this.$t('word.require_username'),
        min: (v) => v.length >= 8 || this.$t('word.login_rules1'),
      },
      password_rules: {
        required: (value) => !!value || this.$t('word.require_password'),
        min: (v) => v.length >= 8 || this.$t('word.login_rules1'),
      },
    });

    const action = {
      login: async () => {
        console.log(
          await getLoginToken({
            username: state.username,
            password: state.password,
          }),
        );
      },
    };

    return { ...toRefs(state), action };
  },
};
</script>
```

When applied as follows, password_show works well, but rules do not apply.

However, as in the code shown as an example, if you subtract it with data() , it works well. What is the reason??

```
  data() {
    return {
      password_rules: {
        required: (value) => !!value || this.$t('word.require_password'),
        min: (value) => value.length >= 8 || this.$t('word.login_rules1'),
      },
    };
  },
```

I want to define it all at once inside setup().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the vue setup function, unlike in `data`, you don't have access to `this`, so `this.$t` is undefined in your rules in the setup function:

```js
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      ...
      username_rules: {
        // can't use "this" here
        required: (value) => !!value || this.$t('word.require_username'),
        // can't use "this" here
        min: (v) => v.length >= 8 || this.$t('word.login_rules1'),
      },
      password_rules: {
        // can't use "this" here
        required: (value) => !!value || this.$t('word.require_password'),
        // can't use "this" here
        min: (v) => v.length >= 8 || this.$t('word.login_rules1'),
      },
    });
    ...
  },
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      password_rules: {
        // "this" is available here because it's in `data`
        required: (value) => !!value || this.$t('word.require_password'),
        min: (value) => value.length >= 8 || this.$t('word.login_rules1'),
      },
    };
  },
```

To access i18n in the setup function you need something like this:

```js
const { t } = VueI18n.useI18n() // call `useI18n`, and spread `t` from  `useI18n` returning
return { t } // return render context that included `t`
```

Here's more on [using i18n with the Vue 3 composition api](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the answers in this post: [How to connect Vue 3 with Vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871984/how-to-connect-vue-3-with-vuetify)

I highly doubt that VueJs3 is compatible with vuetify 2.
Plus, in the vuetify3 documentation https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en, i don't see the v-text-field component yet.

Comment: The [@vue/composition-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) is a package that allows the composition api to be used with Vue 2. So, they are definitely using Vue 2.